# MUI TextField value not completing with RTL

Tags: material-ui, react-testing-library

Setup: React, MUI and React Testing Library.
Minimal example: a component with only a MUI TextField.

Problem: after filling the TextField with RTL (I've tried in several ways), the tests pass, but in debug I can't see any value (checking both with screen.debug() and jest-preview). It's there any way to make the value show?

Component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

export default function MuiMock() {
    const [variable, setVariable] = useState("");   

    return (
        <TextField
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="username"
            label="Username"
            name="username"
            autoComplete="username"
            autoFocus
            onChange={(e) => {console.log('changed!'); setVariable(e.target.value)}}
        />
    );
}
```

Test:

```
import { debug } from "jest-preview";
import React from "react";
import { screen, render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import MuiMock from "./Mock";

it("mock test", async () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup();
    render(
        <React.StrictMode>
            <MuiMock/>
        </React.StrictMode>
    );

    const usernameInput = screen.getByRole("textbox", { name: "Username" });    
    expect(usernameInput).toBeInTheDocument();
    await userEvent.type(usernameInput, "Jay");
    expect(usernameInput).toHaveValue("Jay");
    screen.debug();
    debug();    
});
```

The input is blank:
[image: blank input]

Tried with userEvent.type and fireEvent.change. Both of them didn't work.